# AJAX / jQuery form submission shoutbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm making a simple shoutbox, where a user submits a form which is passed to PHP through a jQuery AJAX request, and their comment shows up on a wall feed.

The PHP / SQLite part is working fine, but I'm having trouble with the AJAX form. When I click submit (post), it processes the PHP correctly at `shout.php` but the navigation window also jumps over to `shout.php` when it should remain on the original page...

HTML form:

```
<form id="newPost" action="shout.php" method="post">

Name: <input type="text" id="name" name="name" />

Message: <textarea name="message" id="message"></textarea>

<input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" />

</form>
```

And the jQuery:

```
$("#newPost").submit(function() {


var name = $("#name").val();
var message = $("#message").val();
var data    = 'name='+ name +'&message='+ message;


$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "shout.php",
    data: data,
    success: function(html) {

        console.log(html);

            refresh_shoutbox();
    }
    });
return false;
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my suggestion for a better maintainability:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#newPost").submit(function(e) {
    $.post({
        $('#newPost').attr('action')
      , $('#newPost').serialize()
      , function(html) {
          console.log(html);
          refresh_shoutbox();
        }
    });
    e.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

Comment: It still had the same problem :(

Comment: Did you use the `e.preventDefault();` ? And don't forget the `e` param in the callback function

Comment: Yep, tried it, your code makes sense, but i think there's a problem with the communication between the jquery and the form...

Comment: Did you try to alert() something at the beginning of the submit callback ? (see also, I changed the `ajax` to `post` simpler to use)

Comment: Is your `$("#newPost").submit()` declared after the form generation, ie in a `$(document).ready()` ?

Comment: Oh snap, it was JUST outside the doc ready bracket...now it works! thank you so so much :)

Answer (score 0):

Try the form without an "action" - because currently you are in essence submitting via ajax and submitting the form normally via its action attribute:

```
<form id="newPost" action="" method="post">
```

Comment: I've tried that, but it won't post to the php file for some reason w/out the action there...it doesn't seem to be registering the jQuery at all

Comment: What does your refresh_shoutbox() do?

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
<input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" />
```

to

```
<input type="button" id="submit" value="Submit" />
```

and then change

```
$("#newPost").submit(function()
```

to

```
$("#newPost").click(function()
```

the input submit type will actually submit the form through a new http request, that's why your page is going to "shout.php" after.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#newPost").submit(function(e) {

    e.preventDefault(); //just add this

    // your rest code
    var name = $("#name").val();
    var message = $("#message").val();
    var data    = 'name='+ name +'&message='+ message;


    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "shout.php",
        data: data,
        success: function(html) {

            console.log(html);

                refresh_shoutbox();
        }
        });
    return false;


    });
```

This will prevent default submit event so navigation window remain on same page.

Comment: I read about something similar to this, but it still does the same thing...I think there might be a problem with the communication between the form and the jquery itself